# Freemarker, list index and count condition

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker

I'm writing a JS Array of objects in a Freemarker template. But I am having serious issues not including a comma after the last item.

```
<#assign pages = module.pages.page>
wh.pages = [
<#list pages as page>
{"name" : "${page.@name}", "href" : "${page.@href}"}
<#if (index+1) < pages?size>,</#if>
</#list>
]
```

So during the list repeat, while index + 1 is less than the length/size of the pages variable, it should write a comma. So that when it equals the size, it should omit the comma.

So how can this be achieved?

Comment: http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_list.html Not how I'd do it, their example seems cleaner.

Comment: Yes that too... was unaware of the "_has_next" function. Was trying to do it old school. Shame you didn't put that as an answer, would of accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Index has to be prefixed with your item name. In example:

```
<#if (index+1) < pages?size>,</#if>
```

should have been:

```
<#if (page_index+1) < pages?size>,</#if>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try with `item_has_next`

In your example:

```
<#if pages_has_next>,</#if>
```

Answer (score 1):

this may be a simple answer

```
<#sep>,</#sep>
```

Comment: This is the best and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of items and using that I am going to create a function with multiple parameters with the comma. My code is as follows:

```
def ${function.name}(<#list function.params as param> ${param.name}:${param.paramType}<#if function.params?size != (param?index+1)>,</#if> </#list>)
```

it will generate the following output:

```
   def func1( input1:String,  input2:String )
```